# Passing --env variables now working with ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

I have a base docker image from which I'm building my own on top of. I do not have the Dockerfile of the base image.

Basically, the base image takes two `--env arg`, one to accept their license and one to select which framework should be activated in the container. I have no problem running my container without an `ENTRYPOINT` as `docker run -it -p xxxx:xxxx --env ARG1=x --env ARG2=y <imageID> /bin/bash`, and then run the script I would run in `ENTRYPOINT` inside the container. That works flawless. BUT! I want to make it work with `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "myscript.sh"]` so that I don't have to go inside the container each time I want to run it. When I use my own entrypoint it's like the container ignore my inputs `--env ARG1=x --env ARG2=y`.

Could it be that the base image has its own `ENTRYPOINT` looking for those environment variables? Is there any way to make sure that the base image stills runs its starting script, and then runs mine after?

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM base-img

USER root

RUN  apt-get update -y &&  apt-get upgrade -y \
        && apt-get install -y nano \
                apache2 \
                iputils-ping \
                vim \
                emacs


USER user1

ENV PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:${PATH}"

RUN conda install jupyter notebook -y

COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /home/user1/.jupyter/

COPY run-jupyter.sh /home/user1

WORKDIR /home/user1

#ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/user1/myscript.sh"]
```

I've even tried echoing them in `~/.bashrc`, but it didnt work... 
As I said above, my fear is that the base image has some scripts running in the startup depending on what `ARG2` is set to..

Comment: Are you able to provide a [mcve] of an image and entrypoint script where the env variables are not being passed?

Comment: If you can `docker run baseimage /bin/sh`, then can you specify a different CMD in your derived image, and still use the base image’s ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `ENTRYPOINT` of the base image with:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' BASEIMAGE
```

(Replace `BASEIMAGE` with name of base image.)

Probably it will work if you include the `ENTRYPOINT` command of the base image in your own `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be that the base image has its own ENTRYPOINT looking for those environment variables? Is there any way to make sure that the base image stills runs its starting script, and then runs mine after?

No, an image will only have a single entrypoint. The one you define in your image replaces any entrypoint definition from the parent image.